# Как с помощью .htaccess организовать поддомены?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php, сервер

Добрый день. Вопрос популярный, но так и не смог сделать, хотя примеров много.
Я испольую `php framework CodeIgniter`.

Как с помощью mod_rewrite сделать что бы:

1. При наборе test.site.ru было обращение `site.ru/test`
2. При наборе test.site.ru/infa было обращение `site.ru/test/infa`

В настройках сервера альяс `*site.ru` стоит. Надо лишь изменть юрл. Так же в `.htaccess` есть такие записи:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

чтобы убрать `index.php` из адреса.
Спасибо.

Comment: [поиск работает](http://hashcode.ru/questions/144249/url-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-htaccess)

Comment: Там идет перенаправление, а нужно что вы url оставался прежним

Answer (score 1):

Копать в эту сторону:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.ru/$1/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```